# Different behaviour of node js process.nextTick() and Promise.resolve() when used with ECMAScript module

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-loop

So I was just going through how event loop works and how it decides call back priority .
I conducted two experiments :
Experiment 1 :

```
Promise.resolve().then(()=>
{
    console.log('promise resolved')
})
process.nextTick(()=>
{
    console.log('next tick')
})
```

gives expected output
but
Experiment 2: same as above but added package.json

```
{
  "name": "nodelearn",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type":"module",
  "main": "hello.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

experiment 1 gives the correct result(expected):

```
next tick
promise resolved
```

but experiment 2 gives unexpected result:

```
promise resolved
next tick
```

next tick callback should be executed first.